# Examples of non-algebraic compact Kahler surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

We call a Kahler manifold of dimension 2 a Kahler surface. 
Kodaira has proved a famous theorem:every compact Kahler surface is a deformation of an algebraic surface. We know every algebraic surface is compact Kahler surface, but inversely, not every compact Kahler surface is an algebraic surface. I don't know any example of such surface, so can anybody provide me an example of non-algebraic compact Kahler surface？The simpler the better, thanks!

Comment: I think I have a few examples of non-compact algebraic surfaces. Did you mean projective varieties or something?

Comment: I mean compact but non-algebraic Kahler surface. Cause every non-singular complex projective algebraic variety is kahlerian, but I need a compact Kahler surface which can not be holomorphicly embedded into complex projective space.

Comment: I was referring to your statement "every algebraic surface is a compact Kähler surface".

Comment: Yeah, I mean projective varieties.

Comment: David Speyer has some examples of nonalgebraic surfaces [here](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/complex-manifolds-which-are-not-algebraic/) which may help you.

Comment: A typical example is a general complex $K3$ surface. By definition this means a simply connected compact complex surface with trivial canonical bundle. There is a 20-dimensional moduli space of such surfaces, but the algebraic ones form a countable union of 19-dimensional subspaces inside that 20-dimensional space. The books by e.g. Barth--Hulek--Peters--van de Ven or Huybrechts explain all this in great detail.

Comment: @ Lazzaro Campeotti  thanks so much for your answer, I must say this is exactly the kind of answer I am looking for! and the reference is very helpful too, by the way, do you have any examples of compact kahler surface with non-trivial holomorphic line bundle which is not algebraic?

Comment: Dear Tom, one can get an example of the kind you want by taking a non-algebraic $K3$ and blowing up a point. There may be more "honest" examples such as elliptic fibrations, but I don't know a lot about this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lattice  $\Lambda \subset \mathbb C^n$ is a discrete abelian subgroup of rank $2n$ generated by a basis $\lambda_1,...,\lambda _{2n}$ of $\mathbb C^n$ seen as a *real* vector space.
The quotient $T_\Lambda=\mathbb C^n/\Lambda$  is a complex compact manifold, called a complex torus and that torus is **always** Kähler because the standard Kähler structure on $\mathbb C^n$ descends to $T_\Lambda$.
For $n=1$ that torus is a projective variety that can always be imbedded in $\mathbb P^2$ (and is then  called an elliptic curve).
For $n\geq 2$ however the torus $T_\Lambda$ is not projective (nor even algebraic) for a general choice of the lattice $\Lambda$.
The necessary and sufficient condition on $\Lambda$ for $T_\Lambda$ to be projective is due to Riemann.
In modern language that condition is that there exist a hermitian structure $H=G+iA:\mathbb C^n\times \mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C$ such that $A(\Lambda \times \Lambda)\subset \mathbb Z$ .

Comment: For $n=2$, does there exist non-trivial holomorphic line bundle $L$ on the torus such that $c(L)$ is not zero?

Comment: On an abelian variety there always exist algebraic line bundles whose first Chern class is non-zero. For example smooth hyperplane sections of the abelian variety are divisors whose associated line bundles have non-zero Chern class. There also exist non algebraic $2$-dimensional tori with line bundles  having non-zero Chern class.

Comment: Choose a non algebraic 2-dimensional tori $X$ with a holomorphic line bundle $L$ having non-zero Chern class $c(L)$ in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$, by the Lefschetz theorem on (1,1) class $c(L)$ is also in $H^{1,1}(X)$, let $K$ be the Kahler cone of $X$ which is a open cone in the positive part of the vector space $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{R})$, so the intersection of Kahler cone $K$ and $H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is not empty, by Kodaira's embedding theorem, $X$ is projective algebraic, which contradicts the assumption that $X$ is non-algebraic, is there something wrong?